# how to verify the syntax of Robot framework code

Tags: robotframework

I have robot framework written in Linux OS. I often get syntax issue in my ROBOT FRAMEWORK code.
Do we have any online compiler or in python to trace where the syntax error is occurring(Which line)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--dryrun` [command line argument](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#dry-run) to check test data validity and syntax.

From the user guide which I strongly suggest to browse in general.

> Robot Framework supports so called dry run mode where the tests are run normally otherwise, but the keywords coming from the test libraries are not executed at all. The dry run mode can be used to validate the test data; if the dry run passes, the data should be syntactically correct. This mode is triggered using option --dryrun.

> The dry run execution may fail for following reasons:
>
> - Using keywords that are not found.
> - Using keywords with wrong number of arguments.
> - Using user keywords that have invalid syntax.

Comment: when I issue robot  test1.robot  --dryrun  , I am getting the error message as  [ERROR ] Parsing '--dryrun' failed: file or directory to execute does not exist.                                          But the file is present in the same path.

Comment: @LakshanthC  You have executed the command with a wrong order this should be used: `robot --dryrun test1.robot`. Arguments should be listed before name of the robot file